# ANTLR: extraneous input '|'

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to alter some syntax in the java.g4 file, one of these is the '||' keyword which I turned into 'or', but when I try to compile it with ANTLR, the parser throws an error:

parser code

[image]

parser error in cmd

[image]

Here is the Java.g4 file:

```
expression
    :   primary
    |   expression '.' Identifier
    |   expression '.' 'this'
    |   expression '.' 'new' nonWildcardTypeArguments? innerCreator
    |   expression '.' 'super' superSuffix
    |   expression '.' explicitGenericInvocation
    |   expression '[' expression ']'
    |   expression '(' expressionList? ')'
    |   'new' creator
    |   '(' typeType ')' expression
    |   expression ('++' | '--')
    |   ('+'|'-'|'++'|'--') expression
    |   ('~'|'!') expression
    |   expression ('*'|'/'|'%') expression
    |   expression ('+'|'-') expression
    |   expression ('<' '<' | '>' '>' '>' | '>' '>') expression
    |   expression ('<=' | '>=' | '>' | '<') expression
    |   expression 'instanceof' typeType
    |   expression ('==' | '!=') expression
    |   expression '&' expression
    |   expression '^' expression
    |   expression '|' expression
    |   expression '&&' expression
    |   expression 'or' expression
    |   expression '?' expression ':' expression
    |   <assoc=right> expression
        (   '='
        |   '+='
        |   '-='
        |   '*='
        |   '/='
        |   '&='
        |   '|='
        |   '^='
        |   '>>='
        |   '>>>='
        |   '<<='
        |   '%='
        )
        expression
    ;

    // §3.12 Operators

ASSIGN          : '=';
GT              : '>';
LT              : '<';
BANG            : '!';
TILDE           : '~';
QUESTION        : '?';
COLON           : ':';
EQUAL           : '==';
LE              : '<=';
GE              : '>=';
NOTEQUAL        : '!=';
AND             : '&&';
OR              : 'or';
INC             : '++';
DEC             : '--';
ADD             : '+';
SUB             : '-';
MUL             : '*';
DIV             : '/';
BITAND          : '&';
BITOR           : '|';
CARET           : '^';
MOD             : '%';
```

Comment: Is the string with all the A's and D's your input to your parser?  What is your actual goal?  Are you trying to process a version of java wich uses 'or' as the logical-or operator? This is just what I think you might be trying; if you want helpful answers here you need to be more precise, clearly state what you're trying to achieve and what exactly is not working.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I only put the ADADADDDD string because I wasn't able to post this due to the code having more content. Yes, you are correct. I am trying to process the version of java to use an 'or' operator as the logical-or operator instead of '||'.

Comment: You replaced `|` parsing and probably messed up handling of single pipes (e.g. for binary or). Try logging your token stream and see what it gives to the parser and then check if that matches your parser rule.